# Methods working in view does not work in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having the below view.

```
Moves: <strong>{{puzzle.api.moves}}</strong>

<button class="button" ng-click="puzzle.api.shuffle()">Shuffle</button>

<sliding-puzzle api="puzzle.api" size="{{cols}}x{{puzzles.cols}}" src="{{src}}"></sliding-puzzle>
```

In the above view, the method shuffle() works fine on the button ng-click event.

```
puzzle.api.shuffle()
```

But when I use that inside a controller, it's not working. I know that puzzle is not available for the controller as its from the custom directive.

How can I use this function inside my controller?

Below is my complete controller.

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, slidingPuzzle) {

    $scope.showOptions = function() {
       puzzle.api.shuffle(); //puzzle is not defined
       $scope.puzzle.api.shuffle(); //puzzle is undefined
    }

});
```

I am using the below given custom directive.

https://github.com/pdanis/angular-puzzle/blob/master/app/js/puzzle/slidingPuzzle.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the answer of @logan looks fine and logical to me, it does not work. As a temporary solution, I have made the code as below and it works.

I know its not an elegant solution, but it works for me, atleast fro now.

As it works in view, I am passing the values to controller.

```
<button ng-click="shuffle(puzzle.api)">shuffle</button>
```

And in controller, I am using it.

```
$scope.showOptions = function(api) {
   api.shuffle(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The directive is relying on you to give it a variable via the `api` attribute that it will populate via bidirectional binding. This is not something you typically see in directives.

If your directive usage in your view looks like this:

```
<sliding-puzzle api="puzzle" size="{{rows}}x{{cols}}" src="{{src}}"></sliding-puzzle>
```

And your controller sets `rows` and `cols`:

```
$scope.rows = 3;
$scope.cols = 4;
```

Then `$scope.puzzle` will be populated by the time you go to use `$scope.showOptions()`.

```
$scope.showOptions = function() {
  $scope.puzzle.shuffle();
};
```

[Plnkr demonstrating this](http://plnkr.co/edit/sj50ch?p=preview). See your console for output.

Comment: This is understandable. But it does not work on my app. I am not able to create a fiddle as it has some copyrighted codes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$scope.puzzle.api.shuffle()` in your controller.
Look at the sample on [angular-puzzle](https://github.com/pdanis/angular-puzzle)

You need to define the puzzle in your controller. In the sample `$scope.puzzles` is defined as follows :

```
 app.controller('slidingAdvancedCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.puzzles = [
            { src: './img/misko.jpg', title: 'Miško Hevery', rows: 4, cols: 4 },
            { src: './img/igor.jpg', title: 'Igor Minár', rows: 3, cols: 3 },
            { src: './img/vojta.jpg', title: 'Vojta Jína', rows: 4, cols: 3 }
        ];
    });
```

As you could see in the sample project, puzzle is an element of puzzles in a for loop.

```
<fieldset id="sliding-advanced" ng-controller="slidingAdvancedCtrl">
        <legend>Advanced</legend>
        <div ng-repeat="puzzle in puzzles">
            <h2>{{puzzle.title}}</h2>
            <div class="src">
                <input type="text" ng-model="puzzle.src"/>
            </div>
            <div class="status">
                moves: <strong>{{puzzle.api.moves}}</strong><br/>
                solved: <strong>{{puzzle.api.isSolved()}}</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="size">
                rows: <input type="text" ng-model="puzzle.rows" size="2"/>
                cols: <input type="text" ng-model="puzzle.cols" size="2"/><br/>
                <button ng-click="puzzle.api.shuffle()">shuffle</button>
                <button ng-click="puzzle.api.solve()">solve</button>
            </div>
            <sliding-puzzle api="puzzle.api" size="{{puzzle.rows}}x{{puzzle.cols}}" src="{{puzzle.src}}"></sliding-puzzle>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

So you can do in your Controller

```
 $scope.puzzles[0].shuffle();
```

Comment: Sorry. I have already tried this. The error will be $scope.puzzle is undefnined.

Comment: It is better to edit your question and use $scope.puzzle. then be sure the directive is inside the HomeCtrl.

Comment: Can you set an online demo?

Comment: I guess you have got it wrong. puzzles and puzzle are two different things.

Comment: puzzles contains multiple pazzle

Comment: Thats wrong. both are 2 different models. I have named it like that.